# Pass an extra param on form submit in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, url

I have a javascript function say `newFn()`. I need to check some condition with `if else`.

```
function newFn(formName)
{
 var codeParam = document.getElementById('code').value; 
 var windowForm = document.forms[formName];     
   windowForm.submit(); 
 return true;           
}
```

**My requirement is :**

`if(codeParam == null)` I need to pass one more parameter say `codeParam=null` else  `codeParam=codeParam` on `windowForm.submit();`.In short in the url I need an extra param.  Is this possible?

Comment: "In short in the url I need an extra param", 
So it is a GET form submit?

Comment: `POST` does not show the parameters in the URL, so I suppose you are asking about having an extra hidden field in the form or updating the already existing field `code`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand exactly what you want to accomplish but

```
function newFn(formName) {
    var codeParam = document.getElementById('code').value;
    if (!codeParam) {
        codeParam = null;
    }
    document.forms[formName].codeParam = codeParam;
    var windowForm = document.forms[formName];     
    windowForm.submit(); 
    return true;
}
```

If (assuming "code" is a textfield) is empty, codeParam is set to null, if it has a value, then codeParam is set to the value.
(i added the propertie to the form as well, so it would get submitted, i don't know if its what you want )

You can take a look at the output of this  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eZB93/)

Answer (score 3):

Why not directly set its value like this:

```
if (codeParam == null) {
    document.getElementById('code').value = 'null';
}
```

This will send a **codeParam=null** form data to your action url.

However I noticed that this code would never be executed, the `value` property of a `input` element could never be the value `null`, when no input is provided, the `value` property's value is a **empty string ('')**, so maybe you should change your logic.